# Retrieve child element in firebase realtime database on singlevalueeventlistener?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase Data Structure [image]

I tried with:

```
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("test1");
    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String name = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
```

but it's not working.

Comment: What about the parent of 'test1'?

Comment: test1 parent is project name

Comment: Create a data object model for the name object, then set its value with the dataSnapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mehmed's answer will work great, but there's an alternative.

If you don't want to create a Java wrapper class, you can also access the property directly from the `DataSnapshot`:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
    Log.d("TAG", name);
}
```

The difference with your code is the addition of the `child("name")` call, which means we're getting the value of the `name` property from the JSON.

Another alternative is to attach the listener directly to the `name` property with:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("test1");
reference.child("name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String name = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }
});
```

This last example has the advantage that it only retrieves the `name` property, even if you later add more child properties under `test1`.

Answer (score 1):

First create a class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String name;

    public MyClass() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(MyClass.class)
    }

    public String getName() {
         return name;
    }
}
```

Then update your code as follows:

```
String myInstance = dataSnapshot.getValue(MyClass.class);
String name = myInstance.getName();
```

Comment: I think this will work.